# Using Json in Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

I'm trying to load some data from an external JSON file, and I don't know why, but my code doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var urlDesc = "http://www.thisurl.com/worksgood/json.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: urlDesc,
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                alert(item);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            alert(urlDesc);
            alert('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    }); 
});
```

The json.php returns something like this:

```
[{
    "color": "red",
    "size": "big"
  }, {
    "color": "white",
    "size": "small" 
}]
```

Comment: What does it mean 'doesn't work'?

Comment: Sorry i posted an incomplete question. Now it is better explained.

Comment: Try changing the url to a public json feed (eg. this [http://jsonip.com/](http://jsonip.com/) and see if that works. If it works, you have a problem in your server response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the Javascript console whilst running your application on a simulator or device?  If using Cordova 5 or higher, it's likely that you need to configure the Content Security Policy meta tag in your index.html to allow access to your server URL.  If using iOS 9 you will also need to configure an App Transport Security exception as iOS 9 will not allow non-SSL connections by default.

If you have these issues, using Safari or Chrome remote debugger should show appropriate errors in the JavaScript console that would look something like this:

```
Refused to connect to '<your server url>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

To fix this, you will need to add a Content Security Policy meta tag in the head in index.html that looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://www.thisurl.com">
```

If you are then running on iOS 9 also, you will need to modify your application's -Info.plist to configure an App Transport Security exception to allow your app to connect to your server without requiring SSL.  Add something like this to the -Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
      <key>www.thisurl.com</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

There is a [detailed blog post](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/) explaining how to configure backend security for Cordova here that points to a sample app that shows you how to get this working on iOS and Android.

Additionally don't do your Ajax call before Cordova/PhoneGap raises the "deviceready" event ([documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html)).